# What am I doing wrong to get Radio Button value?

Tags: vb.net, itext

I'm using PdfStamper to get the field values from a PDF form. I can get the value out of textboxes, comboboxes and checkboxes succesfully using the GetField() function from the Acrofields class. But when it comes to Radio Buttons, I either get the value of the first Radio Button in the set or "Off". What am I missing?Should I get the value differently? Is there a commonly known bug I'm not aware of?
Here's a sample of my code:

```
Private Sub btnFinish_ItemClick2(sender As Object, e As DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs) Handles btnFinish.ItemClick
Dim pdfReader As New PdfReader(savedfile)
    Dim pdfStamper As New PdfStamper(pdfReader, New FileStream(pdf_prefinal, FileMode.Create))
    Dim pdfFormFields As AcroFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields

    Dim pdfFieldscollection As System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary(Of String, iTextSharp.text.pdf.AcroFields.Item) = pdfReader.AcroFields.Fields
    Dim dsNewRow As DataRow = DualReview_databaseDataSet.tblEngineeringReviewTracking.NewRow()

    Dim rqdEmptyFields As New List(Of String)
    Dim rqdCommentFields As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim keepSavingfields As Boolean = True

    'Loop through each field in order to find empty fields and to save fields value
    For Each field In pdfFieldscollection

        Dim fieldName As String = field.Key
        Dim fieldType As Integer = pdfFormFields.GetFieldType(fieldName)
        Dim fieldValue As String = pdfFormFields.GetField(fieldName)
        Dim saveCurrentField As Boolean = False
        '...

    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

All the Radio Buttons in the same "group" should have the same name. Each button should have its own "Export Value". In your code the Name will return once with the value from the selected button. (The property "Export Value" should just be named "Value" IMO.)

Comment: I realized the problem wasn't iTextSharp, instead it was the pdf viewer software I was using that didn't record the radio button value correctly.

Comment: Likely the design of the PDF document is the issue. You'll need a PDF editor to make the changes. I like FoxIt Phantom.